# Sass Compile Error - property[1][0].replace(/progid:DXImageTransform\.Microsoft read property '0' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, libsass

I am having troubles compliling certain lines of `sass` whilst using libsas

I have included the entire error produced with this line of sass:

**SASS**

```
.cboxIE #cboxTopLeft{background:transparent; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="http://images2.moneysavingexpert.com/images/colorbox/internet_explorer/borderTopLeft.png", sizingMethod='scale');}
```

**Error**

```
C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\optimizers\simple.js:176
    property[1][0] = property[1][0].replace(/progid:DXImageTransform\.Microsof
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at minifyFilter (C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\optimizers\simple.js:176:33)
    at optimizeBody (C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\optimizers\simple.js:272:7)
    at _optimize (C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\optimizers\simple.js:316:11)
    at SimpleOptimizer.optimize (C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\optimizers\simple.js:342:3)
    at SelectorsOptimizer.process (C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\selectors\optimizer.js:16:37)
    at C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:185:31
    at run (C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:172:7)
    at minify (C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:184:3)
    at whenSourceMapReady (C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:101:7)
    at C:\var\www\mobile 2\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:117:18
```

How can i compile successfully using libsass?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://sassmeister.com/gist/8342394aee1273de76af.  The error appears to be coming from your minifier.

Comment: wow... Let me check. My god I could kiss you!!! Worth putting as an answer and I'll accept it.